# How can i debug adbd on android？

Tags: android, debugging, adb

adbd is the daemon process running on the device. After a long time running, I found adbd may
receive a sigsegv signal, but this will not be logged in logcat. I have try to make the static libs shared libs, but that does not help.

*Is there anyway to debug adbd?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that.

Jut copy what debugger.c does to  adbd, after receive the signal, just make a socket connect to the debuggerd, and tell it your pid, and it will track you error stack. Then in the logcat,
you can find the error.

But I am really intersted how the orignal developers debug adbd ?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by this. would you please elaborate on this?

Comment: adbd is build in static way, so if you want to debug it with debuggerd, you have to do it manually.